# How To - Learn basic hacking skills?

Tags: linux

I'm interested in learning some basic hacking; and I've read online that Linux is a good place to start.
Although, I've been a Windows user for as long as I can remember. So I was hoping I could get a few tips and maybe even a good tutorial. Thanks! :)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Are you asking for tutorial on linux? That's not the topic of this site - you could try over at serverfault - but I seriously doubt you'd get an instant tutorial, SE is not built or intended for that. If you're asking a specific question - it's not clear from what you wrote...

Comment: I was asking for a tutorial on basic hacking.

Comment: Erm.  Linux != hacking.  You said you wanted to learn how to hack, but then said you heard that Linux was a good place to start, so AviD then told you the better place to go find information on Linux.  You should clarify your question.

Comment: @James, still not the place for it - SE is not a tutorials site, it's focused Q&A. Of course, if you get stuck on something specific we very much welcome any and all specific questions... In the meantime, why dont you search this site for pointers? The [ [education](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/education) ] tag specifically might help you find some good reading materials, books, sites, etc.

Comment: Hold on, I'm still working on trying to rephrase my question.

Comment: Closed for now, to prevent too many scattered and irrelevant answers. @James, feel free to ping me or one of the mods to reopen the question, if you change it to a specific question that can be answered.

Comment: alright, i have to comment that noone has given him a lecture on IT Security vs. "hacking."

Answer (score 4):

Go to local events where you can get hands-on and watch others.

In the Phoenix area, we have

- [HeatSyncLabs](http://www.heatsynclabs.org/)
- [OWASP Phoenix](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Phoenix)
- [BufferOverflow](http://0x539.us/)
- [Arizona Security Practitioners' Forum](http://azspf.org) (AZSPF)
- [Phoenix 2600](http://www.phx2600.org/)

You will want to attend [DEFCON](http://defcon.org) in Las Vegas and probably [Toorcon](http://toorcon.org) in San Diego, because both are 6 hours drive-time from Phoenix. There is also [LayerOne](http://layerone.org) in Anaheim.

Online, you can take the Offensive-Security course called [Penetration-Testing with BackTrack Online](http://www.offensive-security.com/online-information-security-training/penetration-testing-backtrack/). However, I warn you that it is very grueling to learn the material and apply it in the labs -- I would assume 5 or 6 months and 19 hours a day, everyday -- even with resources such as a full subscription to [SafariBooksOnline](http://www.safaribooksonline.com), where you can search for more information and read books online.

I suggest that you purchase a separate laptop, specifically for Linux. Make sure to get one that is [highly compatible with BackTrack Linux](http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/hardware-compatibility-list/). You will want to purchase a separate USB WiFi adapter, such as the Alfa AWUS036H (which is not quite obvious yet, but it's useful to learn the [MITM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) network architecture concepts). If you have Windows installed on a desktop, laptop, or whatever else device -- be sure to install and heavily use Cygwin and/or MinGW, although perhaps you can research those later, when you've already installed and used BackTrack. If you can specify the type (laptop) or graphics chipset options to support [CUDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CUDA) (both NVIDIA and Intel's as options would be nice). Your card will probably be listed on that self-referencing wikipedia article.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking for a lot... I suggest that you start in a "corner" of this website hacking.

My suggestion is that you learn about differnt ways to "hack" a web site. [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) or [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) is a good area to start in. Read about what they can do and how and why it's possible. And if you feel you have a basic understanding of how `XSS` and `SQL injection` work then you can check out [Hack This Site!](http://www.hackthissite.org/) they have a lot of exploitable sample sites and forums discussing them.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for books on the topic I might recommend reading Kevin Mitnick's book:
The Art of Intrusion: The Real Stories Behind the Exploits of Hackers, Intruders and Deceivers.

This book gives a nice introduction to the concepts and the mindset one must be in to be a "hacker."

Another resource I found to be extremely helpful is the CEH (Certified Ethical Hacker) Certification Preparation Handbook. It outlines procedures that White-Hat professionals use to pen-test businesses which is related to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

First:  **Learn some basic programming skills.**  The better programmer you are the better hacker you will become.

Next I would look at vulnerable software,  particularly vulnerable web applications. [Google gruyere](http://google-gruyere.appspot.com/) and [OWASP's WebGoat](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_WebGoat_Project) which particularly is nice because its related to the [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010-Main)